# Django: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: django, orm, django-rest-framework

> i am getting error while i extracting the value in my AUTH_USER_MODEL
>   table. any help, would be appreciated.

views.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class AllUser(ListAPIView):
    model = AUTH_USER_MODEL
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = AUTH_USER_MODEL.objects.all()
```

serializers.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = AUTH_USER_MODEL
       fields = [
           "username",
           "email",
       ]
```

Comment: Use `get_user_model()` method instead (you can import it `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model`). `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` is just a string, which can be used when you define a model, (e.g. `ForeignKey` accepts a string) but not when you need the actual class.

Comment: post the error traceback

Comment: i tried it first, but it gave me all users even some users aren't active in my database. i want users who are active users.  have any suggestion, how to do it @dirkgroten

Comment: queryset = AUTH_USER_MODEL.objects.all()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'objects'  @Mirza715

Comment: @SatyajitBarik that has nothing to do with get_user_model(). That's just because your queryset uses `all()`, change that to filter the users you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `get_user_model()` method instead (you can import it `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model`):

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class AllUser(ListAPIView):
    model = User
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()  # or User.objects.filter(is_active=True)
```

`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` is just a string, which can be used when you define a model, (e.g. `ForeignKey` accepts a string) but not when you need the actual class.

See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) for a detailed explanation.